# Forcing Routing in codeigniter using regex

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

i have following route in route.php in codeigniter

```
$route['^(?!login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin).*'] = "pages/bpages";
```

it is redirecting everthing to pages/bpages except (login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin )

```
eg www.mysite.com/sohailanwarpk
```

as sohailanwapk is not in (autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin) it will redirected to pages/bpages 
the problem i am facing is in that condition if my url is like

```
eg www.mysite.com/autosss

eg www.mysite.com/jobs123
```

it should direct autosss or jobs123 to "pages/bpages"; but its not,so how can i exaclty match (autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin) so that everything else will be redirected.

Comment: I get it that you want `jobs` to pass, `jobs123` or `fooo` too fail. But what about `jobs/123`?

Comment: i have rules in htaccess for these..(login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin) these are basically controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into 2 routes:

```
$route['^(?!(login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin)).*']  = "pages/bpages";
$route['^(login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin)[^\/].*'] = "pages/bpages";
```

Comment: Hi thanks.. i want autosss and jobs123 to work like sohailanwarpk because autosss is not equal to autos and * - GOT YOU is only with sohailanwarpk in your test case too

Comment: I misunderstood the question, so I updated the answer. Now `jobs123` & `sohailanawrlk` both have `GOT YOU`. `jobs` or `jobs/foo` will PASS =)

Answer (score 0):

Just write 2 rules:

```
$route['^(login|signup|autos|jobs|jobwanted|admin)$'] = '$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/bpages';
```

Comment: what about urls like `login/foo/bar`?

Comment: Any URL will be routed to `pages/bpages`